# How to add rows in a dataframe by a column condition python

Tags: python, row, addition

I have a dataframe like that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022],

'month': [1,2,3,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,1,2,3,4,5],
'client':[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3],
'total':[10,20,30,55,4,64,88,5,64,32,84,24,69,70,54,11,37,98,52]})
 df

    year  month  client  total
0   2022      1       1     10
1   2022      2       1     20
2   2022      3       1     30
3   2022      1       2     55
4   2022      2       2      4
5   2022      3       2     64
6   2022      4       2     88
7   2022      5       2      5
8   2022      6       2     64
9   2022      7       2     32
10  2022      8       2     84
11  2022      9       2     24
12  2022     10       2     69
13  2022     11       2     70
14  2022      1       3     54
15  2022      2       3     11
16  2022      3       3     37
17  2022      4       3     98
18  2022      5       3     52
```

I would like to have for all the clients 12 months, so I need to add this rows and assign the value 0 to the column total. For this new rows, the value of the year column is a copy of the rows that have filled the month up.

Desire output:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'year': [2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,20 
 22,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022,2022],

'month': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12],
'client':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3],
'total': 
[10,20,30,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,55,4,64,88,5,64,32,84,24,69,70,0,54,11,37,98,52,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]})
df
    year  month  client  total  
0   2022      1       1     10
1   2022      2       1     20
2   2022      3       1     30
3   2022      4       1      0
4   2022      5       1      0
5   2022      6       1      0
6   2022      7       1      0
7   2022      8       1      0
8   2022      9       1      0
9   2022     10       1      0
10  2022     11       1      0
11  2022     12       1      0
12  2022      1       2     55
13  2022      2       2      4
14  2022      3       2     64
15  2022      4       2     88
16  2022      5       2      5
17  2022      6       2     64
18  2022      7       2     32
19  2022      8       2     84
20  2022      9       2     24
21  2022     10       2     69
22  2022     11       2     70
23  2022     12       2      0
24  2022      1       3     54
25  2022      2       3     11
26  2022      3       3     37
27  2022      4       3     98
28  2022      5       3     52
29  2022      6       3      0
30  2022      7       3      0
31  2022      8       3      0
32  2022      9       3      0
33  2022     10       3      0
34  2022     11       3      0
35  2022     12       3      0
```

Maybe by the merge option there is a solution? I've tried but without a good result

Comment: I fixed your input data. Row#14 should be for client 3 not 2 according your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the easiest way but it works with `pivot_table`:

```
out = (df.pivot_table(index=['year', 'client'], columns='month',
                      values='total', fill_value=0.)
         .reindex(columns=range(1, 13), fill_value=0.)
         .stack().swaplevel('month', 'client')
         .rename('total').reset_index())
```

Output:

```
>>> out
    year  month  client  total
0   2022      1       1   10.0
1   2022      2       1   20.0
2   2022      3       1   30.0
3   2022      4       1    0.0
4   2022      5       1    0.0
5   2022      6       1    0.0
6   2022      7       1    0.0
7   2022      8       1    0.0
8   2022      9       1    0.0
9   2022     10       1    0.0
10  2022     11       1    0.0
11  2022     12       1    0.0
12  2022      1       2   55.0
13  2022      2       2    4.0
14  2022      3       2   64.0
15  2022      4       2   88.0
16  2022      5       2    5.0
17  2022      6       2   64.0
18  2022      7       2   32.0
19  2022      8       2   84.0
20  2022      9       2   24.0
21  2022     10       2   69.0
22  2022     11       2   70.0
23  2022     12       2    0.0
24  2022      1       3   54.0
25  2022      2       3   11.0
26  2022      3       3   37.0
27  2022      4       3   98.0
28  2022      5       3   52.0
29  2022      6       3    0.0
30  2022      7       3    0.0
31  2022      8       3    0.0
32  2022      9       3    0.0
33  2022     10       3    0.0
34  2022     11       3    0.0
35  2022     12       3    0.0
```

After the pivot your dataframe looks like:

```
>>> (df.pivot_table(index=['year', 'client'], columns='month',
                    values='total', fill_value=0)
       .reindex(columns=range(1, 13), fill_value=0))

month          1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    11  12
year client                                                                      
2022 1       10.0  20.0  30.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0
     2       55.0   4.0  64.0  88.0   5.0  64.0  32.0  84.0  24.0  69.0  70.0   0
     3       54.0  11.0  37.0  98.0  52.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0
```

Comment: The only thing is that the total value for the first month is changed after pivot.  For the client 2 the value was 55 and has changed into 54.5 and for the client 3 was 54 and has changed aswell into 0.

Comment: Check your data Row#14. It should be client 3 and not 2 for 2022-01. It works if I fixed the data from my side, can you check the output now?

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a DataFrame with all possible combinations of 'year', 'month', and 'client'

```
all_combinations = pd.DataFrame([(y, m, c) for y in df['year'].unique() for m in range(1, 13) for c in df['client'].unique()], columns=['year', 'month', 'client'])
```

Merge the original DataFrame with the generated combinations, filling NaN values with 0 in the 'total' column

```
result_df = pd.merge(all_combinations, df, on=['year', 'month', 'client'], how='left').fillna({'total': 0})
```

Sort the DataFrame by 'client', 'year', and 'month' for a neat display

```
result_df = result_df.sort_values(by=['client', 'year', 'month']).reset_index(drop=True)
```